# asp.net webservice with jquery on different domain

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services

I got to work on PHP app which requires a webservice call to an Asp.net webserivce. Client insist to call this webservice with POST directly via jquery.

My knowledge says its not possible to call different domain webservice from JS and I'll have to create a proxy page to consume this webservice.

So I just want to confirm, is there any hack around to consume webservice directly from jQuery POST call and parse response (Which is XML not JSON) on page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way around it x-browser. Server Proxy or json-p are your choices.

Comment: I had quite a lot of hassle with json-p, and ended up going with the server proxy.

Comment: jsonp works well. I use it all the time. Look at some big online services (flickr, yahoo) they all use jsonp.